# Lua tracking state of a userdata from C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have Frames that can be shown from a Lua script as follows:

```
frm=MainFrame.new()
```

When user runs this command, a frame pops up and is shown. The Frame class has member functions such as `add`, `close`. Now **without** running `frm:close()` the user can also go and click on the window's close button and thereby close the window. After this action, if the user runs the following command:

```
frm:add()
```

the program crashes due to memory violation as `frm` is not `nil` but was deleted behind the scenes from C++ using `delete` command. However, Lua is not aware of this and what it is referring in memory has already been deleted. Is there a way to make the `frm` variable `nil` when the memory it is referring is deleted from C++.

By the way the user can run `frm1=Frame.new()` and `frm2=Frame.new()` where both `frm1` and `frm2` are of type Frame but assume that only `frm1` is closed by clicking on the window close button and therefore only `frm1` is deleted from C++ side.

I am using tdm-gcc mingw 4.8.1 on Windows 10 therefore regular `try` and `catch` blocks does not help to catch memory violations.

EDIT 1:

Lua wrappers:

```
int MainFrame_NumberofFrames(lua_State* L)
{
    MainFrame* mframe= luaW_check<MainFrame>(L, 1);
    int NumWorkSheets=0;
    NumFrames=mframe->GetNumberOfFrames();
    lua_pushnumber(L,NumFrames);
    return 1;
}

int MainFrame_AddNewFrame(lua_State* L)
{
    int nargs=lua_gettop(L);

    MainFrame* mframe= luaW_check<MainFrame>(L, 1);
    if(nargs==1){
    if(!mframe->AddNewFrame(wxEmptyString)) luaL_error(L,"Unexpected error occurred");
    }
```

Internal C++ code:

```
MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{
    //Omitted for brevity

    if(m_FrameList) {delete m_FrameList; m_FrameList=0;}
}

bool MainFrame::AddNewFrame(const wxString& tblname, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    m_NumberofFrames++;
    wxString TableLabel=tblname;
    if(TableLabel.IsEmpty())  TableLabel=_T("Frame")+wxString::Format(wxT("%i"),m_NumberofFrames);
    //Let's check if Frame with the same name exists
    if(!TableLabel.IsEmpty()){
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<m_FrameList->Size();i++){
        Frame* subframe=m_FrameList->GetEntry(i);
        if(subframe->GetName()==TableLabel) return false;
    }
 }
```

If I run:

```
frm:count() --It returns even though the main frame is closed
```

However, when I run:

```
frm:add()
```

The program crashes as `m_FrameList` variable was deleted when the main frame was closed by user.

Comment: Did you write the Lua binding around the C++ code? For me this looks like a bug in the Lua binding.